# Query for first 3 posts to change the look and feel

Tags: posts, wp-query, query-posts, query

Is there a way to query for the first three recent posts and then change how they display on the front page?

I want the first three posts of my blog to show differently than the rest of them i.e. they will have full images, and my other posts will just have thumbnail previews.

Thanks for any help in the matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can style the first 3 posts differently without querying them separately, you just need to check where you are within the loop while outputting each post via the built in `current_post` var.

```
while( have_posts() ):
    the_post();

    // are we on the first page and outputting one of the first 3 posts?
    if( !is_paged() && $wp_query->current_post < 3 ):
        // output full image, etc..
    else:
        // not first page and not first 3 posts
        // output just thumb, etc..
    endif;

endwhile;
```